# how to insert current date into access database?

Tags: ms-access, c#-4.0

Actually im creating one application where i inserted user sales count, sales count is updating fine but when i edit in query by putting current date its not updating detail
Here im putting whole code

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.txtinput.MaxLength = 4;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Login set Sales_count= IIF(IsNull(Sales_count), 0, Sales_count) + 1 where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No and [To_Date]='#"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"#'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique_No", txtinput.Text);
                con.Open();
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");// **Debugger come to this line if i insert [To_Date]='#"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"#'** // if i remove above line in code then its updating fine 

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    }



                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

for reference pasting access table detail
[image]
[image]

Comment: SQL-Server <> MS Access... Perhaps you need to escape the double quotes for your date format. e.g. `ToString(\"dd/MM/yyyy\")...` ?

Comment: The record you have posted (`User_ID022`) does not have a value in the To_Date column. Therefore no records will be updated with the code you have posted. If you want that record updated you need to remove `and [To_Date]='#"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"#' ` in your code. Or you need to enter today's date in the `To_Date` column before updating.

Comment: @bjones : but what i want when i tried to update sales_count at same time current date also insert in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL supports a `Date()` function which the db engine can use to determine the current date.  So you don't need c# code to take the current date and concatenate it (eek!) into the text of your SQL statement.  And you don't need to feed the date as a SQL parameter (which is less nasty), either.  Simply let the db engine determine `Date()` for itself.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Login set Sales_count= IIF(IsNull(Sales_count), 0, Sales_count) + 1 where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No and [To_Date]=Date()", con);
```

That suggestion was based on the SQL statement in your question.  However, in the comments, it sounds like you want to change `To_Date` values to today's date for some records.  I'm not clear about which records should be changed, so no idea what you need for a `WHERE` clause.  But to update `To_Date` values to today's date, the Access SQL should start like this ...

```sql
UPDATE Login SET To_Date = Date() WHERE ...
```

Comment: hi , i modified in query 
update Login set Sales_count= IIF(IsNull(Sales_count), 0, Sales_count) + 1, [To_Date]=Date() where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No and its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime toDay = DateTime.Now;

        this.txtinput.MaxLength = 4;
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Login set Sales_count= IIF(IsNull(Sales_count), 0, Sales_count) + 1 where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No and [To_Date]= @to_day", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique_No", txtinput.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_now", toDay.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            con.Open();
            int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (n == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");// **Debugger come to this line if i insert [To_Date]='#"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"#'** // if i remove above line in code then its updating fine 

                }
                else
                {
                    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }



            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: still debugger coming on 
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later") line

Comment: @Atul are you sure you have records in your table that contain the information you are inputting through the application? Have you tried `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE [Unique_No]=@Unique_No and [To_Date]= @to_day`, with the respective values in place?

Comment: @bjones : for reference i edited access database detail also

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments provided, you need to `SET` the date. In your original query, you are using it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime toDay = DateTime.Now;

    this.txtinput.MaxLength = 4;
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Login set Sales_count= IIF(IsNull(Sales_count), 0, Sales_count) + 1, [To_Date]= @to_day where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique_No", txtinput.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to_Day", toDay.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        con.Open();
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (n == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");// **Debugger come to this line if i insert [To_Date]='#"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"#'** // if i remove above line in code then its updating fine 

            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }



        con.Close();
    }

}
```

You also had incorrect syntax which I have updated. Let me know if the above query works.

Comment: still debugger went to below line 
    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");

                    }